# Unable to git push due to filename casing after merging unrelated histories

Tags: git

Trying to combine one repo into another repo while maintaining history using the following rough method:

- Clone repo to be moved/merged (source) and `git mv` all files/folders into a subfolder that does not exist in the destination repo
- Commit and push changes
- Create a new branch in the repo to be merged into (destination)
- Add a remote to the source repo: `git remote add source-repo <path to remote>`
- `git fetch source-repo`
- `git merge remotes/source-repo/<branch_to_merge> --allow-unrelated-histories`
- `git push`

This worked great for several repos but on this one particular repo, I get the following error when trying to do that last push up to origin:

```
Enumerating objects: 10703, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10703/10703), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3460/3460), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10697/10697), 2.08 GiB | 82.72 MiB/s, done.
Total 10697 (delta 7494), reused 10216 (delta 7135), pack-reused 0
error: remote unpack failed: error The tree object 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9 was rejected: The file 'datetimeRangeOutput.json' and the file 'dateTimeRangeOutput.json' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them or disable case-enforcement (see https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat).
remote: Analyzing objects... (6458/10697)
To http://<remote_repo>
 ! [remote rejected]     merge_repos -> merge_repos (The tree object 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9 was rejected: The file 'datetimeRangeOutput.json' and the file 'dateTimeRangeOutput.json' pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them or disable case-enforcement (see https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat).)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://<remote_repo>'
```

Trying `git show` and `git ls-tree` shows me the following which clearly does show a file with the same name and blob  that differs only in casing:

```
git show 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9
tree 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9

dateTimeRangeOutput.json
datetime.PNG
datetime.rst
datetimeBasic.json
datetimeRangeBasic.json
datetimeRangeOutput.json
datetimeUnboundedRange.json
datetimerange.PNG

git ls-tree 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9
100644 blob e55dd6082aac6c68c36fcb97fbb58f245c9edecf    dateTimeRangeOutput.json
100644 blob 4a4e321469e9833e88acabec37ad7ee9a7846d24    datetime.PNG
100644 blob 698a530c3a7d072b8f2eb25d919324a54d5b05d3    datetime.rst
100644 blob cbf11401b753506e34a9876cafcb257d946c918b    datetimeBasic.json
100644 blob 430a0be3e61b962db69937af378963d884beedcf    datetimeRangeBasic.json
100644 blob e55dd6082aac6c68c36fcb97fbb58f245c9edecf    datetimeRangeOutput.json
100644 blob e2c834e636d0e3c8781f93ad8bb3ec1a3ded7cb7    datetimeUnboundedRange.json
100644 blob 20ba2ec51c702d9ebeebe67e14e905cfc33fabfb    datetimerange.PNG
```

I've tried `git mv` the filename to another name and then back. I've tried `git rm` on the file (it's like a 2 line file that I can replace later if need be). I don't know where to go from here so that I can get this pushed up to the remote and ultimately merged into development branch.

**Update to Maybe Make Clearer**

I have tried `git rm` on the file in the source repo **Before** adding it as a remote to the destination repo. The repo/filesystem does not have the conflicting file at all in either repo on their respective branches at the time of push and I STILL get the same error.

*Note 1: I've tried performing the steps on both Windows and Linux and have had the same results.*

*Note 2: It's possible that the same file (contents) with the different casing existed somewhere in the destination repo in the past but never at the folder location it exists in this push and it does not currently exist in the branch I'm pushing to at any location.*

Comment: I've encountered this before.  The *EASIEST* approach is probably 1) use Git bash (which is case-sensitive), 2) `git mv` one or other of the files to bring both names in sync with each other 3) `git add/git commit`.  At that point, everything should work OK.

Comment: @paulsm4 Right, as stated in Note 1, I've tried this on linux which is case sensitive and we have run into "normal" casing issues before that I have resolved doing your method. This, however, is different because the file does not actually exist on the remote branch with a different casing and certainly not at that location. I've tried `git mv` as stated in the question and it hasn't solved the problem :(

Comment: ERROR (from git push): `The file 'datetimeRangeOutput.json' and the file 'dateTimeRangeOutput.json' pushed differ in case.`  SOLUTION: 1) pick a repo (whichever is easiest for you).  2) git bash (or equivalently, Linux command line) `git mv <<current-name>> <<new-name>>` 3) stage and commit your change to that repo 4) You should now be OK to push that repo.  That should work.  Honest.  If it doesn't, [Edit] your post and show the EXACT COMMANDS (and ERROR msgs) for that file - and that file only.

Comment: @paulsm4 I already said I did the git mv. You aren't reading the whole question or my reply to your comment. I've even completely deleted the file from one repo. It has to be related to the file existing at some point in the history. The file does not currently exist at all in the destination repo.

Comment: I completely disagree with your "history" premise, and I'm guessing that's probably why things aren't working.  Just focus on getting "push" to work.  You might need to (re)create the file, you might still need another "git mv".  You might also consider a "git pull" first.

Comment: See my edit update to the question. I have already tried completely removing the file from the source repo using `git rm` so that at the point of merging, it didn't exist and at the point of pushing it didn't exist in EITHER repo and yet I still get the same error. That's why I believe it has to be related to the file existing at one point in time or in some other branch.

Comment: @paulsm4: note: it's not that *bash* is case sensitive (though it normally is), but rather that *Unix/Linux* is case sensitive, and bash normally runs on these systems. Working with case issues in Git is much easier if you do it on a case-sensitive OS. (Technically it's the file system, not the OS, that decides whether files named ReadME and README are two different files, or the same one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message that you are getting:

> ```
> error: remote unpack failed: error The tree object
> 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9 was rejected:
> The file 'datetimeRangeOutput.json' and the file 'dateTimeRangeOutput.json'
> pushed differ in case. You must remove or rename one of them
> or disable case-enforcement (see https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat).
> ```

is not actually from *Git*.  It is from an add-on that Microsoft stuck in on their Azure server.<sup>1</sup>  Please visit https://aka.ms/git-platform-compat (as the error message advises) for full details on what they're doing.

The error is not specifically due to the use of `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  It is instead due to the snapshot in at least one particular commit:

> ```
> The tree object 83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9
> ```

This refers to some commit(s) (whose hash ID(s) is or are not actually `83f05a173307d3874ab7a304ed3019d2c0af9fe9`, which makes the error message relatively low quality; it's probably the merge you made, though).  A *tree object* is how a commit stores a snapshot, so each commit—which stores one snapshot—has one.  Multiple commits can share one tree object; that's not terribly common (though easy to arrange) and probably is not the case with this particular repository.

The commit itself, as a result of your merge, contains the two files outlined:

> ```
> datetimeRangeOutput.json
> dateTimeRangeOutput.json
> ```

There are two ways to handle this despite the fact that you're using Azure:

- You can [disable the test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops).
- You can make your merge commit such that it has only *one* of these two files.

The latter is the only *Git* option; the former is an *Azure* option.  (Hence the distinction.)

To achieve the latter, run `git merge` with the `--no-commit` option:

```
git merge <insert any other desired options here> --no-commit <merge-specifier>
```

Git will perform the merge as usual, but then *stop before committing*.

Git builds a *new commit* not from the files in your working tree, but rather from the files in Git's index.<sup>2</sup>  **These files are not stored in your file system's format** and Git can therefore store both `datetimeRangeOutput.json` *and* `dateTimeRangeOutput.json`, and in this case, it is doing exactly that.  (Use `git ls-files --stage` to see this.)

You can now pick *one* of those two files to use and remove the other one, or remove both and insert the correct one, using `git rm --cached` and/or `git add`:

```
git rm --cached datetimeRangeOutput.json dateTimeRangeOutput.json
[edit and/or rename the working tree copy as needed]
git add dateTimeRangeOutput.json    # with whatever case you wanted
```

Git will make the new commit from what's in its index, and after updating the index appropriately, you can run:

```
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
git commit
```

(these have the same effect).  The snapshot you've prepared *in* Git's index will now be used to make the new commit.  The `git merge` you ran built a new set of files in Git's index.  If there was a conflict, it stopped regardless of your `--no-commit` option.  If not, it stopped only if you said `--no-commit` (or `--squash` which implies `--no-commit` for no good reason).  So here, you say `--no-commit` to force it to stop, so that you can *modify* the proposed new commit before going on to finish the merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>This may be a distinction without a difference as far as you are concerned, but it's useful to some folks, so I make it.

<sup>2</sup>This thing—Git's *index*—has three names, for no particularly good reason:

- The index, which is the name I use above.
- The *staging area*, which is where `--stage` comes from in `git ls-files --stage`.
- The *cache*, which is where `--cached` comes from in `git rm --cached`.

Because Git is inconsistent about which one it uses, you'll need to be aware of all three names.  While the index takes on an expanded role during conflicted merges, its main role is to hold your *proposed next commit*.  Everything you do in Git, as far as Git is concerned anyway, is really all about updating Git's index so that you can make new commits.  Files in your working tree are just useless junk, except for when you `git add` them to copy them into Git's index.  The index controls the next commit, and commits are the reason Git exists, so the index is what matters here.

Comment: Great explanation! I left the office so I won't be able to try this until tomorrow but will report back then.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried these steps but nothing changes. When I do the `git merge -n`, it doesn't actually stop the merge, the merge just completes. Note that I don't get any conflicts/errors when I merge locally. Only when I go to push up to origin.

Comment: I disabled the case enforcement on the repo and that worked. Still annoyed that it was necessary and sort of don't understand why it's conflicting even when no version of that file exists in the repo but at least it unblocked me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oops, you need `--no-commit`. What the heck does `-n` *do?* It's in the synopsis but not in the man page... Ah, `-n` = no diffstat.